# Custom module for 'Buy one get one free (BOGO)' functionality

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I am developing custom module for 'Buy one get one free (BOGO)' functionality.
I am done with custom form and grid at admin side for setting mapping of product-X and product-Y for BOGO.
I have written observer for `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event to check respective product-Y for currently added product and also successfully getting respective mapped product.
But I am stuck (since yesterday morning) at adding product-Y in cart programmatically.
I have tried below code:

```
$prodY = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(<ID_OF_MAPPED_PROD-Y>);
if($prodY) {
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($prodY, array('product_id' => $prodY->getId(), 'qty' => 1));
    $cart->save();
}
```

My web store is crashing here and I am unable to find any error.
What wrong I am doing here?
Can anyone please help me to get out of this situation?
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: what do you mean by "crashing"? Please provide us at least with the exact error message. You may want to have a more verbose output with error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @Jojo: I am getting following error...  "The 127.0.0.1 page isn’t working"....

Comment: @Jojo: when error reporting is turned on.. I am getting following erro.... `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`

Comment: @Jojo: issue is resolved.. find link in my own answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event handler was getting called recursively... 
Issue is resolved.. Refer link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112818/custom-module-for-buy-one-get-one-free-bogo-functionality